# LIMIT 1 Not Working in SQL Query Builder in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: mysql, sql, visual-studio-2012, limit, query-builder

I am trying to build a query using sqldatasource where it only shows the most recent column in a table.

```
    SELECT* FROM CustomerB
    ORDER BY CustomerID DESC
    LIMIT 1
```

This function works in the w3schools website, but The error is with the LIMIT 1 in the query builder. The error I get says unable to parse query text, and the query cannot be represented graphically in the diagram and the criteria pane. and the Error message is incorrect syntax near 'LIMIT'

Comment: I associate Visual Studio with SQL Server, not MySQL.  That datbaase uses `top` instead of `limit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you're using SQL Server try

```
SELECT TOP 1 *
  FROM CustomerB
 ORDER BY CustomerID DESC
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/279cf/1)** demo

Answer (score 0):

```
Select * from CustomerB Order By CustomerID DESC Limit 0 , 1 ;
```

for last position if you want last 2 customer id then use

```
Select * from CustomerB Order By CustomerID DESC Limit 0 , 1 ;
```

and if you want only 2nd last customer id then use

```
Select * from CustomerB Order By CustomerID DESC Limit 1 , 1 ;
```

for last 3rd position value

```
Select * from CustomerB Order By CustomerID DESC Limit 2 , 1 ;
```